# If $A_n \subseteq B_n$, then $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n \subseteq \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that if $A_n \subseteq B_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n \subseteq \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n$ and $\cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n \subseteq \cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} B_n$?

Comment: $$a \in \bigcup A_n \iff a \in\ ???\ \exists\ ???\ \implies a \in\ ??? \implies a \in\ ???$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. We can use $A_n\subseteq B_n$ or $x\in A_n\implies x\in B_n$ to get:

$$x\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\implies \exists_{n_0\in\mathbb N}\,x\in A_{n_0}\implies x\in B_{n_0}\implies x\in\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N} B_n.$$

Also,

$$x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N} A_n\implies\forall_{n\in\mathbb N}\,x\in A_n\implies\forall_{n\in\mathbb N}\,x\in B_n\implies x\in\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n.$$

This implies $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\subseteq\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$ and $\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}A_n\subseteq\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$.